# Gelfand-Kazhdan criterion, exposition by Paul Garrett

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Here is Paul Garrett's exposition on the [Gelfand-Kazhdan Criterion](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/gelfand_kazhdan.pdf).

In page 4 of the exposition, he showed the following lemma.

> Lemma (Page 4): Let $B, t, S$ be as above and for $\alpha, \beta$ in $C_c^\infty(G)$, we have
> $$B(\alpha \otimes \beta) = t( S(\beta \ast \alpha)).$$

In his proof, he states the following
$$B(\alpha \otimes \beta) = T\alpha (S \beta) = \int_G \alpha(x) t(x \cdot S \beta) \, dx =\int_G \alpha(x) t( S (R_x^{-1} \cdot \beta)) \, dx.$$
The first equality follows directly from definition, however I am unable to verify the second equality.

However, in page 3 of his exposition, he proved that $S(R_g \eta) = g \cdot(S \eta)$ for any $g \in G$ and $\eta\in C_c^\infty(G)$. So, should the expression of $B(\alpha \otimes \beta)$ be evaluated as the following instead
$$B(\alpha \otimes \beta) = \int_G \alpha(x) t (S( R_x \cdot \beta)) \, dx.$$